# Is possible use TelecomManager in Delphi for Android?

Tags: android, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Is possible use TelecomManager in Delphi 10.2.3 for Android?

The embarcadero source codes do not have this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarcadero provides a [Java2OP tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android) to allow Android apps to access most Java APIs that are not natively wrapped by FireMonkey's RTL.

Comment: I understand, Remy.
I used the command: Java2OP.exe -classes android.telecom.TelecomManager


I have one question now: How to specifify, which Android API is used as source?